# How can I send traces to Jaeger from C#?

Tags: c#, jaeger

I'm trying to use the [Jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-csharp) package to send traces to Jaeger from a C# app.

There are no minimal examples in the jaeger-client-csharp documentation, but from what I read, I think this should work.

```cs
using Jaeger;
using Jaeger.Samplers;

namespace jaegertest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tracer = new Tracer.Builder("my-service")
                .WithSampler(new ConstSampler(true))
                .Build();

            using (var scope = tracer.BuildSpan("foo").StartActive(true))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have jaeger-all-in-one.exe running but when I run this code there's no sign of any new traces. I've tried manually configuring samplers, senders, reporters, etc. but nothing I tried worked. What do I need to add to get my traces to appear in Jaeger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest working example that I was able to find.

```cs
using Jaeger;
using Jaeger.Reporters;
using Jaeger.Samplers;
using Jaeger.Senders.Thrift;

namespace jaegertest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tracer = new Tracer.Builder("my-service")
                .WithSampler(new ConstSampler(true))
                .WithReporter(new RemoteReporter.Builder()
                    .WithSender(new UdpSender())
                    .Build())
                .Build();

            using (var scope = tracer.BuildSpan("foo").StartActive(true))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            tracer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a more realistic example that builds the tracer from a configuration.

```cs
using Jaeger;
using Jaeger.Samplers;
using Jaeger.Senders;
using Jaeger.Senders.Thrift;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace jaegertest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();

            var samplerConfiguration = new Configuration.SamplerConfiguration(loggerFactory)
                .WithType(ConstSampler.Type)
                .WithParam(1);

            var senderResolver = new SenderResolver(loggerFactory)
                .RegisterSenderFactory<ThriftSenderFactory>();

            var senderConfiguration = new Configuration.SenderConfiguration(loggerFactory)
                .WithSenderResolver(senderResolver);

            var reporterConfiguration = new Configuration.ReporterConfiguration(loggerFactory)
                .WithSender(senderConfiguration)
                .WithLogSpans(true);

            var tracer = (Tracer)new Configuration("my-service", loggerFactory)
                .WithSampler(samplerConfiguration)
                .WithReporter(reporterConfiguration)
                .GetTracer();

            using (var scope = tracer.BuildSpan("foo").StartActive(true))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            tracer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```